# phpMyAdmin plus app for iphone Format

Tags: ios, swift

I made an app that takes the data from a database and displays it in the tableView on my application. The small issue im having is that when I go to my php file, it displays what I need to see but when the app gets it, it displays "Optional" after the name of each column.

What in phpMyAdmin is making it to where the app is reading optional?

I added some screenshots

[image: php file onlineenter image description here]

[image: iphone app]

Comment: code? or its not a real question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It represents that the value of those field might be nil or present. The case is, the values can be nil or available, so ios compiler not sure about the values presence.

When you will use those values in your programming, Before assigning and operating on those values you can be sure that the value is available there or not by below procedure.

You can check those value individually by using **if let**, It will remove optional from the value and operation on it if the value is not nil.

```
//Your optionalValue will be assigned to value.
if let value = optionalValue {

     //if value is present there, then it will remove the optional and print the value with Hello.
     print("Hello, \(value)")
}else{
     //if value is nil, then it will print 'value is nil' in console.
     print("value is nil")
}
```

I hope you understand, for more clarification and specification please check apple basic swift documentation.